# Converting a column of String to integers?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

```
`# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(dataset, column):
      class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
      unique = set(class_values)
      lookup = dict()
      for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
      for row in dataset:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup`
```

The above code is the most basic machine learning snippet to convert a column of string to integers(or one hot encoding).However I am having difficulty understanding the code esp. `class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
unique = set(class_values)` what does these two lines do that makes it to do one hot encoding?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dataset = [
...     [1, 2],
...     [1, 2],
...     [1, 2]
... ]
>>> column = 1
>>> class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
>>> class_values
[2, 2, 2]
>>> unique = set(class_values)
>>> unique
{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

So `class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]` is what is called a list comprehension. It is shorthand way to create a list in python. This statement is the equivalent of saying:

```
class_values = []
for row in dataset:
    class_values.append(row[column])
```

These are extremely common in Python, so definitely read about them and practice with them. They make your code cleaner and save time.

Set can be ready about here: [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

In short, they are a grouping that is unique. So if you make a set of a list you get an object with all the unique values from the list

Comment: Sets are a type of *unordered collection* too. So they're not index. They also have an average lookup time of O(1). Important additional statements